# Is it possible to have 1 pivot table from 2 workbooks?

Tags: excel

I've been using Excel a lot lately and I'm not quite familiar with Pivot table. Is it possible for me to combine 2 workbooks into 1 pivot table? The first workbook is about the days of leave of the employee and the second one is about the days that the employee is present. They have similar fields which is the internal ID. I was wondering if there's a way to combine the two workbook to make it 1 pivot table only. I tried the connection in excel that helps connecting my two workbooks but that will make 2 pivot tables. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the free add-in [Power Query](https://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=39379) for Excel 2010 and 2013, or the built-in Get & Transform in Excel 2016 to combine data from different workbooks.

Create a query into the first workbook table and save it as a connection only. Then create a query into the second workbook table. Make sure the columns have identical names and are of the same data type. Then click append to combine with the first query, load to the workbook and create a pivot table as usual.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that one and update you if it worked for me :)

Comment: When I create a query for the second workbook, should it be saved as connection as well?

Comment: No. You can query the table, make the adjustments and then append the first query. You need to save the first query as a connection, so it does not take up storage space and so it is available to the second query as a data source.